# Creating field which holds stretch of length in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I need to prepare a layout in arcmap, in which i have to show the table showing road stretch and width.
Example - Stretch   -   Width
         0 to 5 km  -    10m,
         5 to 12 km -    07m
Like this....
I have segment wise length in my attributes, which is showing like a below image.[image]

For example road HHD68 starts with HHD68A at 0m and ended at 4019m, HHD68B started at 4019m and ended at 4053m, and so on up to HHD68M.

Comment: You might find it easier to complete your table in Excel and then embed it into your layout. The .dbf file of a shapefile can be opened by Excel *but do not save*, rather *save as type XLS*, saving a dbf in Excel will break the shapefile.

Comment: Do you want to 1) group road segments using field `subroad ID` and then classify each road by length or 2) classify road segments without grouping?

Comment: @BERA Yes, it's not the same road, that is why i have arrowed only same road segments in above image, u can see that HHD68A length is 4019m, HHD68B is 33.97m, i need to represent in a table as a stretch in which 0 TO 4019 M and 4019 To 4053 m (4019 + 33.97 = 4053approx) and so on. How to do this?

Comment: @Mr.Che I need to classify each road segment (HHD68A) by it width. Example- HHD68A started at 0M and ended at 4019M its width is 10M, like wise HHD68B started at 4019M and ended at 4053M its width is 7M. How to do this?

Comment: @BERA I want to group by start and end point of that segment (Assumption - HHD68A is started at 0M and ended at 4019M, HHD68B started at 4019M and ended at 4053M, and so on upto HHD68M) highlighted A to C just to make professionals understand, Actually as u mentioned it goes up to HHD68M.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write python function and run a [field calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm) with it.

As mentioned by [Michael Stimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15054), if you need to do that once - the easiest way is to:

1) Copy table into excel.

2) Sort table by `Sub road ID` field

3) Create column `Text` in excel and using formulaes fill it with values you need.

4) Copy `Text` column values.

5) Create new text field in ArcGIS.

6) Paste `Text` values into vector file.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Che. really it worked. Thank you.